# Words count pipeline with SNAKEMAKE

Tags: python, snakemake

I'm starting to learn how to use Snakemake and I want to do a very simple pipeline to count the number of words in the source file and write the result to the output file. The pipeline should work economically, if the result file is already received, the calculation should not be repeated. My snakefile so far :

```
rule count:

input: 

    "source.txt"

output: 

    "result.txt"

run: 

    file = open("source.txt", "r+")

    data = file.read()

    words = data.split()

    print(len(words))
```

It gives me the result but It don't create the output file and store the result inside. I think the proper way is to use shell and not run, and to specify to run the count words python script ? Or to use Script ? I've tried several ways but nothing seems to work effectively...

Thank you.

Comment: In addition to the excellent replies you already got, this type of activity is the one used in [the Datacarpentry Snakemake Lesson](https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/workflows-snakemake/). It's a great lesson from no knowledge of snakemake through to full use, and so working through that may help you understand snakemake a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

You just printed the result you never actually wrote anything to a file

```
with open('result.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    f_out.write(len(words))
```

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the answer by @Cory Kramer, below is how the rule could look like:

```py
rule count:
   input: text_file = "source.txt",
   output: result_file = "result.txt",
run:
    # read data
    with open(input.text_file, "r+") as file:
       data = file.read()

    # run calculation
    words = data.split()

    # save result
    with open(output.result_file, 'w') as f_out:
       f_out.write(len(words))
```